# How to move to lines with the same indentation in gVim (or any other text editing tools)?

Tags: vim, text-editor

How can I move to next and previous lines with same Indentation in gVim (or any other text editing tools).
For Eg:

```
This is first line
    Second line
          Third Line
    Fourth Line
          Fifth Line
Another Line
    Last Line
```

Here if I place cursor at 'S' of Second Line and press some keys, I need to go to Fourth and Last lines (having the same indentation as Second Line).

Comment: [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_to_next/previous_line_with_same_indentation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vim, I think the easiest way would be to yank the indenting whitespace and search for it. You could map a key to this. Something like:

```
:nnoremap <F3> 0y^/^<C-R>0\s\@!<CR>
```

- `0y^` jumps to the beginning of the line and yanks to the first text
  on the line
- `/^` starts a search beginning at the start of a line
- `<C-R>0` places the yanked text (the indentation) into the search
  pattern
- `\s\@!` requires that the text after the matched indentation is not further whitespace (see `:help` `/zero-width`)
- `<CR>` performs the search

Note this will fail on lines with no indent since there is nothing to copy between the beginning of the line and the first text on the line.

It will also stop working when you get to a line with *only* indent, although it can reach those lines.

Comment: This does the trick to search forward. Thanks!!. Can we do anything similar to search backward?

Comment: Got it. I used Shift-n after pressing F3 to go to previous lines. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also use `?` in the mapping instead of `/` to do a backwards search.

Comment: Note, this also fails, if the indent changes from space to tab

Comment: Yep, not sure how to get around that. Match any number of spaces up to a virtual column snagged from the current line, maybe?

Comment: A custom function that returns the indent level (indent() function) for the current line and then searches explicitly for /^\s\{<indentlevel>\}\s\@! should do it.

Comment: Doesn't that suffer the same problem with tabs?